# ASP.NET using foreach to populate table is creating empty <td>

Tags: html, jquery, css, asp.net, razor

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC 5 and I am at the point of learning how to populate a table with data I created using a database. I see the data populating just fine(see pic below) but the second column is not getting populated correctly.

Updated Image
[image]

I dont know how to style the table so that doesn't happen. This is where I will need your help.

This is how I have my Index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<Vidly.Models.Customer>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customers";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="customers" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Discount Rate</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach (var customer in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink(customer.Name, "Details", "Customers", new {id = customer.Id}, new {@class = ""})<td>
                <td>@customer.MembershipTypes.DiscountRate<td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
    $('#customers tr').each(function() {
        if ($(this).children('td:empty').length === $(this).children('td').length) {
            $(this).remove(); // or $(this).hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

And this is the _Layout.cshtml where this "partial view is getting referenced:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    @Html.Partial("_NavBar")
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Vidly</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/lib")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

If there is anything I'm missing let me know and I will provide all the feedback necessary to help resolve this issue. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You end the first <td> in the foreach loop with another <td>, not </td>.

Comment: @VDWWD Thank you for the prompt response. See my updated message. After making the change I got some more extra empty <td> in my table. Thoughts?

Comment: Same problem, you're still using `<td>` instead of `</td>`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you're so right. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks to VDWWD suggestion I managed to resolve my issue. I made some adjustments to my table cshtml file only:

```
    <table id="customers" class="table table-bordered table-hover"> 
<tr>
    <th>Customer</th>
    <th>Discount Rate</th>
</tr>

@foreach (var customer in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink(customer.Name, "Details", "Customers", new {id = customer.Id}, new {@class = ""})</td>
        <td>@customer.MembershipTypes.DiscountRate</td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

The issue was I wasn't closing the  in the foreach loop for the first data entry. so, naturally I was creating (inadvertently) those empty  elements.

As I stated earlier I'm  learning the ins-and-outs of this amazing framework. Its really fun. I hope this answer helps anyone else who might stumble into this issue.

Thank you again.